# CSOM Update File Document MetaData in a Subfolder of a library. Getting Error File Not Found

Tags: csom, metadata, spcontext

0

I have a list of urls that are documents in a subfolder of a library.

When I go to update the metadata of a document in the library but not in a subfolder code works as expected.

But some documents in the list are in a subfolder. The URL has the fully qualified path to that document that includes the subfolder.

I can paste the url into a browser and open the document so I know it is correct, but when I get to the

context.Load(file, f.ListItemsAllFields); Context.ExecuteQuery(); -- Error Happens on URL of file in subfolder

I am getting an error stating "File Not Found."

See Code... Again works if file is in root of Library just not when file is in a subfolder.

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates SharePoint MetaData for a specific document
/// </summary>
/// <param name="urlfilepath">The URL including file name of the file to be updated</param>
/// <param name="values">this is a dictionary of propertyName and value to be updated.</param>
private void UpdateMetaData(string urlfilepath, string library,Dictionary<string, string> mydictionary)
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext(qsURLSite))
    {
        context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        var web = context.Web;

        // Get drop off library and edit all items without making changes
        context.Load(web, w => w.Lists);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        List dropOffLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);


        context.Load(dropOffLibrary, dl => dl.RootFolder.Files);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        var file = dropOffLibrary.RootFolder.Files.GetByUrl(urlfilepath);

        context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = file.ListItemAllFields;


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in mydictionary)
        {
            // entry.Key has to be in the property list of that document
            // the name is very specific
            try
            {
                newItem[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
            }
            catch
            {
                // Key was not found in list
                // go to next key

            }
        }
        newItem.Update();
        //file.Update();
        context.Load(file);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        context.Load(dropOffLibrary, dl => dl.RootFolder.Files);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file using a caml query.

```
private void UpdateMetaData(string urlfilepath, string library, Dictionary<string, string> mydictionary)
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext(qsURLSite))
            {
                context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                var web = context.Web;

                // Get drop off library and edit all items without making changes
                context.Load(web, w => w.Lists);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                List dropOffLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);


                context.Load(dropOffLibrary);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                //make sure urlfilepath is the relative path of the file
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>  
                                             <Query> 
                                               <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>"+ urlfilepath + @"</Value></Eq></Where> 
                                            </Query> 
                                         </View> ";
                ListItemCollection itemCollection = dropOffLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);


                if (itemCollection != null)
                {
                    context.Load(itemCollection);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    if (itemCollection.Count > 0)
                    {

                        context.Load(itemCollection[0]);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        var file = itemCollection[0].File;

                        context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = file.ListItemAllFields;


                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in mydictionary)
                        {
                            // entry.Key has to be in the property list of that document
                            // the name is very specific
                            try
                            {
                                newItem[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
                            }

                            catch
                            {
                                // Key was not found in list
                                // go to next key

                            }
                        }
                        newItem.Update();
                        //file.Update();
                        context.Load(file);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        context.Load(dropOffLibrary);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

RecursiveAll will get the files from subfolders as well. Just pass the relative URL in the caml query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up getting to work...

eq is a record number I needed to use to create the subfolder or look in that subfolder.

```
      /// <summary>
      /// This procedure uploads documents to the Authorizations Library
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="filename">File Being Uploaded</param>
      /// <param name="p">file in bytes</param>
      /// <param name="library">Library to upload to</param>
      /// <returns></returns>
        private string UploadToSharePoint(string filename, byte[] p,string library)  //p is path to file to load
        {
            string newUrl;
            string siteUrl = string.Empty; 


            siteUrl = qsURL + @"/repository/current/";
            // Calculate block size in bytes.
            int blockSize = fileChunkSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024;



            //Insert Credentials

             Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(siteUrl);

            context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web site = context.Web;

            if (context.HasPendingRequest)
                context.ExecuteQuery();

            try
            {

                //Get the required RootFolder
                string barRootFolderRelativeUrl = library;

                // Getting Folder List to see if EQCode Folder Exists  If not create it.

                string eq = txtEQCode.Text;
                FolderCollection folders = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl).Folders;   //list.RootFolder.Folders;
                context.Load(folders, fl => fl.Include(ct => ct.Name)
                .Where(ct => ct.Name == eq));
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                if (folders.Count < 1)  // Create Folder because it does not exist on SharePoint Library
                {
                    folders.Add(eq);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder barFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder currentRunFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + eq);

                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation newFile = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation { Content = p, Url = filename, Overwrite = true };
                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(p);

                FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();

                // This is the key difference for the first case – using ContentStream property
                flciNewFile.ContentStream = stream;
                flciNewFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fixInvalidCharactersInFileName(filename));
                flciNewFile.Overwrite = false;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = currentRunFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);

                currentRunFolder.Update();
                context.Load(uploadFile);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                newUrl = siteUrl + barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + filename;

                // Set document properties
                // Have to check out document to upldate properties.

                uploadFile.CheckOut();

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;

                // Sets up ListItem fields based on Content Type 
                // as each content type has a different set of Required Fields.

                SetUpListItems(listItem, EQCode);

                listItem["Title"] = filename;
                listItem.Update();

                uploadFile.CheckIn("File Uploaded Manually added metadata", Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                //Return the URL of the new uploaded file
                return newUrl;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error Uploading!", "alert('" + e.Message + "');", true);
                return "FALSE";
            }
        }
```